# Read the table after a specific line and count occrences with awk

Tags: command-line, bash, awk, text-processing

I have a table somewhere in a big log file which looks like this example:

```
----------------------------
CARTESIAN COORDINATES (A.U.)
----------------------------
  NO LB      ZA    FRAG    MASS        X           Y           Z
   0 C     6.0000    0    12.011         -8.817666638854597         -4.911814574090662         58.264165798697491
   1 C     6.0000    0    12.011         -7.879568488830738         -4.388761616508626         55.950914108733443
   2 C     6.0000    0    12.011         -7.790669273242299         -4.339145245237274         60.527363919786708
   3 C     6.0000    0    12.011         -7.070247938157430         -3.937287748509576         62.694740665963295
   4 C     6.0000    0    12.011         -7.244178391763230         -4.034368638160922         53.748929835486599
   5 H     1.0000    0     1.008         -6.427462410780078         -3.581016558829315         64.562423911622218
   6 H     1.0000    0     1.008         -6.674286700050606         -3.718319003596096         51.850593400164620

--------------------------------
INTERNAL COORDINATES (ANGSTROEM)
--------------------------------
```

I want to tell `awk` to find the `CARTESIAN COORDINATES (A.U.)` then find `NO LB` then starts reading the second variable in each line until it reaches the blank space before `-----`.

So, I will read all the (elements Carbon (`C`) Oxygen (`O`) Hydrogen (`H`)) `C`'s `H`'s and ... then I get how many `C`'s `H`'s.

I have and I get to make a variable like `C5H2` in this case, it may end up be anything like `C3OH4`, any ideas?

```
awk '
/CARTESIAN COORDINATES (A.U.)/ {fcart=1}
fcart &&
/  NO LB/ {scart=1}


/---------------------------/{exit}
' OFS="\t" "$FILENAME"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this `awk`:

```
awk '/CARTESIAN COORDINATES \(A.U.\)/{a=1;next} a==1&&/NO LB/{b=1;next} $0==""{exit}
a==1&&b==1{c[$2]++} END{for(i in c){printf "%s%s", i,c[i]}}' file
```

- `/CARTESIAN COORDINATES \(A.U.\)/{a=1;next}`: This block searches for `CARTESIAN COORDINATES (A.U.)` and then sets the variable `a` to `1`, `next` means to jump to the next line and start the processing again with that line.
- `a==1&&/NO LB/{b=1;next}` checks if `a` is `1` and if the second string `NO LB` is found somewhere in the line. It sets the variable `b` and then loads the `next` line.
- `$0==""{exit}`: Then if the line is empty exit the processing (it jumps to the `END{}` block).
- `a==1&&b==1{c[$2]++}`: If both matches are found (`a` and `b` equal `1`) increment an array called `c` with index `$2` (field 2). This will count the occurences of each value in the second field.
- `END{...}`: This will run when the file processing is done (the array is filled).

  - `for(i in c)` run trough each element in the array...
  - `printf "%s%s", i,c[i]`: ... and print the index and the value.

---

The output (with your example file):

```
C5H2
```

Comment: state machine FTW!

Comment: @A.B. ^^ Today i'm thinking in awk: `awk 'BEGIN{stand_up("very early")} {work("hard");} END{print "need sleep"; goto("bed"); exit}' me`

Comment: @chaos `awk 'BEGIN{stop_using_awk("anti_awk_campaign")}END {print "no_more_awk"}'` -> `Output: FATAL ERROR !!!` ;)

Comment: just to make sure it works if I have a third element there as well right like O, right?

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi If the second field in the table contains an `O` it will be separately counted and printed as well.

Comment: the only issue was it did not exit when reaching "INTERNAL COORDINATES (ANGSTROEM)" but great thanks you have my respects!

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi I changed it to `$0==""{exit}` to stop processing when the empty line appears.

Comment: is it possible to put the C5H2 in a variable?

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi Yes, just put the whole awk command in brackets: `var="$(awk ...)"`

Answer (score 4):

Yet another awk version:

```
awk '/NO.*[[:blank:]]LB/,/INTERNAL COORDINATES/ { 
        if($1~/[0-9]/){count[$2]++;}} 
      END {for(i in count){printf "%s%s",i,count[i]}print ""} ' file
```

This is sort of a mix between Serg's answer and Chaos's. It will only run between lines matching `NO.*[[:blank:]]LB` and `INTERNAL COORDINATES`. The `count` array only counts on lines whose first field is a number.

---

If your file is exactly as you show it where successive blocks of data are separated by an empty line, you can use Perl's "paragraph mode" which treats paragraphs as lines:

```
perl -00ne 'next unless /CARTESIAN COORDINATES \(A\.U\.\)/; 
            $count{$_}++ for (/\s+\d+\s+(\w+)\s/g); 
            print "$_$count{$_}" for keys(%count)' file
```

#### Explanation

- `-00`: turn on paragraph mode;
- `next unless /CARTESIAN COORDINATES \(A\.U\.\)/;` skip this paragraph if it doesn't match `CARTESIAN COORDINATES (A.U.)`;
- `$count{$_}++ for (/\n\s+\d+\s+(\w+)\s/g)` : the regular expression looks for one or more whitespace characters (`\s+`), followed by one or more digits (`\d+`), one or more whitespace characters again and then one or more  word characters (`\w+`) followed by a whitespace character. This should identify all elements. `%count` is a hash, an associative array. It has keys and each key is associated with a value. The `$count{$_}++ for ...` will save each of the matches of the regex above as a key in that hash and increment its value by one each time it is found. The result is a hash that stores the elements and the number of times each was found.
- `print "$_$count{$_}" for keys(%count)` : for each of the elements (the keys of the hash `%count`), print the element and the number of times it was found.

Run on your example file, this returns:

```
$ perl -00ne 'next unless /CARTESIAN COORDINATES \(A\.U\.\)/; 
            $count{$_}++ for (/\s+\d+\s+(\w+)\s/g); 
            print "$_$count{$_}" for keys(%count)' file 
C5H2$
```

That lacks the final newline, however, so you can add it with:

```
$ perl -00ne 'next unless /CARTESIAN COORDINATES \(A\.U\.\)/; 
                $count{$_}++ for (/\s+\d+\s+(\w+)\s/g); 
                print "$_$count{$_}" for keys(%count); print "\n"' file 
C5H2
```

Answer (score 2):

chaos's answer works very well to accomplish what you want. Here's a simpler alternative just in case,

```
awk 'BEGIN{}
$2 ~ /^C$/ { countC++; } $2 ~ /^H$/ { countH++ }
END { print "C",countC,"H",countH; }' OFS="" file
```

Gives the output `C5H2`.

Comment: the big issue was not looking for a specific C or H just looking to the second element and see how many times it's repeated in the same form it can be C2O3H5 or C3SiH3O

Comment: Note that there's no reason to initialize variables to 0 in the BEGIN block. You can just use them directly: `awk '$2 ~ /^C$/ { countC++; } $2 ~ /^H$/ { countH++ }END { print "C",countC,"H",countH; }' OFS="" file`

Comment: @terdon Thanks for pointing that out, i have updated my answer accordingly too.

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi My bad, check out chaos's answer, it works very well to that purpose

Answer (score 2):

Here's a somewhat simpler code:

```
awk '/NO.*[[:blank:]]LB/,/INTERNAL COORDINATES/ { if ( $2 == "C")  counterC++; if ($2 == "H") counterH++  } END {print "C"counterC"H"counterH} ' coordinates.txt
```

Sample output:

```
$ awk '/NO.*[[:blank:]]LB/,/INTERNAL COORDINATES/ { if ( $2 == "C")  counterC++; if ($2 == "H") counterH++  } END {print "C"c>
C5H2
```

Comment: the big issue was not looking for a specific C or H just looking to the second element and see how many times it's repeated in the same form it can be C2O3H5 or C3SiH3O

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi I see.  Let me fix that then

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi will it be fine if the code just outputs number of each element ? Because making up the complete formula probably will be too complex of a code

Comment: it's ok chaos code seems to work fine, thx